# Using not supported events in Backbone

Tags: jquery, events, plugins, backbone.js

Im trying to use not default jquery`s events,
defined in plugin. (exactly "jquery.event.drag" plugin)

Whether it is possible to do something like:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    ..
    events: {
        'pluginEvent': 'handleFunction'
    }     
    ..
}
```

e.g by extending somehow Backbone.Events ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the plugin supports attaching an event handler using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), it should be fine.

Backbone's Views simply delegate to jQuery for binding events by calling `this.$el.on(eventName, method);`.